# Row level formula with Contains for two strings

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

The format for the CONTAINS formula is IF(CONTAINS(Product_Type__c, "part"), "Parts", "Service"). Is there a way to require "Product_Type__c" to also contain a second term in addition to "part" in order to count as TRUE?

```
IF(CONTAINS(field_name, "term1" && "term2"), "Yes", "No")
```

and I got:

> "Error when encoding row-level formula: Incorrect parameter type for
> function 'and()'. Expected Boolean, received Text"

I'm fairly sure it's something simple and I'm just missing it for some reason.